# Cannot resolve interface return type in class

Tags: java, interface

Going to try and be more specific this time.

The overall idea:

- Needed to create a date class which implements the elapsed
  interface.
- Interface was given by instructor, but been labelled incorrect by users here.
- Instructor not interested in helping, summer class almost over.

I cannot get the class date to allow me to give the return type date.

The interface code:

```
public interface elapsed 
{
/* 
 * a year can have 365 or 366 days
 * depending on "leap-year".
 * February can have 28 or 29 days
 * also depending on "leap-year"
 */

public static final int days_week = 7;
public static final int weeks_year = 52;

//add any number of days to a date
public date addDays (int d);

//subtract any number of days from a day
public date subDays (int d);

}
```

So class date has to use subDays and addDays. Ok. I decided not use subDays because I can flip the value of whatever is entered for integer d and use the same math.

So my class date looks like:

```
public class date implements elapsed
{

int day;
int month;
int year;

public date (int Day, int Month, int Year)
{
    day = Day;
    month = Month;
    year = Year;
}

public date ()
{

}

public int getDay()
{
    return day;
}

public int getMonth()
{
    return month;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public date addDays (int x)
{
    int d = getDay();
    int m = getMonth();
    int y = getYear();

    m = (m + 9) % 12;
    y = y - (m / 10);
    int g = (365 * y) + (y / 4) - (y / 100) + (y / 400) + (( m * 306 + 5) / 10) + ( d - 1 );

    g = g + x; //adds days to the g variable which is the date from clock start

    y = (10000 * g + 14780)/3652425;
    int ddd = g - (365 * y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400);

    if (ddd < 0) //manages the occurrences of leap years
    {
         y = y - 1;
         ddd = g - (365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400);
    }

    int mi = (100 * ddd + 52) / 3060;
    int mm = (mi + 2) % 12 + 1;
    y = y + (mi + 2) / 12;
    int dd = ddd - (mi * 306 + 5) / 10 + 1;

    return new date(dd, mm, y);
}

public date subDays (int x)
{
    int d = getDay();
    int m = getMonth();
    int y = getYear();

    m = (m + 9) % 12;
    y = y - (m / 10);
    int g = (365 * y) + (y / 4) - (y / 100) + (y / 400) + (( m * 306 + 5) / 10) + ( d - 1 );

    g = g - x; //subtracts days to the g variable which is the date from clock start

    y = (10000 * g + 14780)/3652425;
    int ddd = g - (365 * y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400);

    if (ddd < 0) //manages the occurrences of leap years
    {
         y = y - 1;
         ddd = g - (365*y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400);
    }

    int mi = (100 * ddd + 52) / 3060;
    int mm = (mi + 2) % 12 + 1;
    y = y + (mi + 2) / 12;
    int dd = ddd - (mi * 306 + 5) / 10 + 1;

    return new date(dd, mm, y);     
}

public String toString(int day, int month, int year) // formats the date into something nicer
{
    String formMonth = null;

    switch(month)
    {
    case 1:
        formMonth = "Jan";
        break;
    case 2:
        formMonth = "Feb";
        break;
    case 3:
        formMonth = "Mar";
        break;  
    case 4:
        formMonth = "Apr";
        break;
    case 5:
        formMonth = "May";
        break;
    case 6:
        formMonth = "Jun";
        break;
    case 7:
        formMonth = "Jul";
        break;
    case 8:
        formMonth = "Aug";
        break;
    case 9:
        formMonth = "Sep";
        break;
    case 10:
        formMonth = "Oct";
        break;
    case 11:
        formMonth = "Nov";
        break;
    case 12:
        formMonth = "Dec";
        break;
    default:
        System.exit(0);
    }
    String formDate = day + formMonth + year;
    return formDate;
}

} //class end brackets
```

I need that addDays to return a date but I cannot figure out how to do it or what syntax to use. I feel like the interface wasn't given to us properly, but what do I know.

I just need it to render a new date so that in my main I can just use something like 
date d2 = d1.addDays(x);

The put it into the tostring that I have to build and make it look nice.

Does this question make more sense?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Suggestion: Have Class names be capitalized - it's the accepted convention and will make reading your code easier.  ex: `Date` instead of `date`.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. But remember that `date` is not a method but a constructor. Try to replace `return this.date(date(dd, mm, y));` with `return new date(dd, mm, y);`

Comment: @tobias_k I tried that as well, but the error switches to the: return type is incompatible with elapsed.addDays(int) error. It does clear away errors on the return line of the method though.

Comment: **Going to try and be more specific this time. … Does this question make more sense?** Is this just a reworking of your previous question, [My Java interface and abstract method nightmare … (now with code)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24899173/1281433)?  If it is, you should delete this question and *edit* that one with improvements.

Comment: @Adam Can not reproduce. When I do this, the code shows no more errors (except for the missing `subDays`)

Comment: If it says "cannot resolve date" or "incompatible with interface", maybe the problem is that those two classes lie in two different packages and you forgot to import them properly?

Comment: @tobias_k at line 37 in the class, I have the lightbulb and red x for multiple markers. One says implements elapsed.addDays(int) and the other is the incompatible error. Maybe eclipse isnt playing nice?

Comment: Both are in the default package, just checked.

Comment: @Adam When I copy your exact code into the default package, I only get the errors that subDays is not implemented, toString has the wrong return type (should be String), and that there is not method date(int,int,int) (it's a constructor).

Comment: @tobias_k thanks much. Im not sure whats going on. I went ahead and finished the code for subDays and toString.

Not sure why but both lines 37 and the one that starts subDays both have the incompatible with elsapsed.addDays(int) or elapsed.subDays(int) respectively.

Comment: and fixed! I had to add "abstract" in front of the types in the interface. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking here, so this is more like a wild guess, but I'm somewhat confident.

In your `addDays` method, you want to create and return a new date. You do so by taking the data from the current date and adding the given days to those values, then calling the `date` constructor to return a new instance. So far, you are on the right track! The only problem seems to be, that a constructor is not a method of the instance that is invoked like `this.date(...)`, but has to be invoked like `new date(...)`.

```
public date addDays (int x) {
    int d = getDay();
    int m = getMonth();
    int y = getYear();

    // date adding logic, did not check, assuming to be correct

    return new date(dd, mm, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is that you only want addDays() to be returning a date, then just do the following:

```
public date addDays(int x)
{
    return new date(dd,mm,yy);
}
```

also

```
public String toString()
{

}
```